# FFMPEG: preset not found in Windows Vista

Tags: ffmpeg, windows-vista

I download FFMPEG from http://www.videohelp.com/tools/ffmpeg#download and saved it in my c:\program files\ffmpeg (Windows Vista). My `Path`'s first 2 entries are:

```
c:\program files\ffmpeg\bin;c:\program files\ffmpeg\presets;
```

I found the following command on the net (http://paulrouget.com/e/converttohtml5video/)

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -acodec libvorbis -ab 96k -vcodec libx264 -vpre main -level 21 -refs 2 -b 345k -bt 345k -threads 0 -s 320x240 output.mp4
```

When I run this on command line, I get the following error:

`File for preset main not found`

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to http://ffmpeg-users.933282.n4.nabble.com/Presets-location-on-Windows-td2253144.html basically the current ffmpeg distro has its presets in the "wrong location" so you need to set the FFMPEG_DATADIR environment variable, or specify the full path to the preset, like

```
 ffmpeg.exe -i a.avi -fpre g:\installs\ffmpeg-20120519-git-31dfe20-win32-static\ffpresets\libvpx-1080p.ffpreset -f webm yo.webm
```

Answer (score 0):

The examples in link you provided uses older ffmpeg syntax. Also, `main` is not a preset but a profile. So instead of `-vpre main` use `-profile main`. If you omit the preset then the default will be used which is `-preset medium`.

General usage is to use the slowest preset you have patience for. See [FFmpeg: The ultimate Video and Audio Manipulation Tool](http://blog.superuser.com/2012/02/24/ffmpeg-the-ultimate-video-and-audio-manipulation-tool/) for a good and up-to-date usage guide and more information on using presets.

Other Junk: I'm not sure what browsers will support Vorbis in the MP4 container format. libx264 ignores `-bt 345k` and  `-threads 0` is now automatically applied so those options are superfluous.

Comment: Thanks. I will try your suggestions. FFMPEG has way too many options for me to understand. Do you have any suggestions on an "optimum" command I can use on a user-uploaded video or audio that I need to convert for display on the web? If possible, I'd like to use the same command for any given input file. My goal is to output it to something high quality and ideal for the web. Uploaded videos and audios won't be huge as I'll put a reasonable limit to the file size that can be uploaded.

Comment: Are you planning on using HTML5 video and/or a flash player for display on the web?

Comment: I think I should support both, right? So, an OGG, MP4 and FLV??? This is such a headache.